# preg_match_all for <li> elements

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to return the count of a list. The list looks like:

```
<div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li class="some classes">1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I just can't figure out how to get a count of the `li` tags. I don't care about the contents, just the count. This is what I have:

```
preg_match_all('!<div id="list">.*?<li.*?>.*?</li>.*?</ul>!', $content, $matches);
```

Ugly I know, and I only receive one match when I `count($matches[0]);`

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong and/ or why?

Thanks

EDIT: I know parsing HTML with regex is [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), but I have little choice in the matter right now.

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/722762 TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention I have no choice right now... but thanks for your concern :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div id="list">.*?<li.*?>.*?</li>.*?</ul>
                                 ^^^
```

The part I'm pointing out is consuming all the characters until `</ul>` (even the `<li>` parts). After consuming them, there no more to match and it ends here, giving only one match.

Comment: If you want to find a solution for that, you might use the regex [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/cZ3dB1) which counts all the `<li>` within a set of `<ul>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work in almost all cases:

```
<?php
$t='<div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li class="some classes">1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
</div>';

$list_array=explode("</li>",$t);
echo "total in list = ".count($list_array);
?>
```